# Error: Connection in subscriber mode, only subscriber commands may be used

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe, node-redis

I found error to push message data in Redis. Kindly provide me some guideline about error. why this happen? I would like to store chat data in redis using nodejs.

server.js (server):

```
/*
 * -------------------
 * Express
 * -------------------
 */
var app = require('express')(),
        session = require("express-session");

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    next();
});
app.set('host', "localhost");
app.set('port', 8080); //process.env.PORT

/*
 * -------------------
 * Socket Connections
 * -------------------
 */
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(app.get("port"), app.get("host"), function () {
    console.log("Server up and running...");
});
io.set('log level', 3);

/*
 * -------------------
 * Redis 
 * -------------------
 */
var redis = require("redis");
/*
 *  Sender
 */
var publisher = redis.createClient();
/*
 * Receiver
 */
var subscriber = redis.createClient();
/*
 * -------------------
 * Mysql
 * -------------------
 */
/*var mysql = require("mysql");
 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
 host: "localhost",
 user: "root",
 password: "password",
 database: "w"
 });
 connection.connect();*/

/*
 * -------------------
 * functions
 * -------------------
 */
function subscribeMessage(_subscriber) {
    subscriber.subscribe(_subscriber);
    subscriber.on("message", function (channel, message) {
        console.log("redis connection message:" + message);
    });
}
function pushToRedis(data) {
    subscriber.lpush('wchannel', data);
}

/*
 * -------------------
 * Redis Subscriber
 * -------------------
 */
subscriber.subscribe("wchannel");
subscribeMessage("wchannel");
/*subscriber.on("message", function (channel, message) {
 //console.log("client channel recieve from channel : %s, the message : %s", channel, message);
 });*/

/* 
 * -------------------
 * Socket
 * -------------------
 */
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {    
    console.log("app port :: " + app.get("port"));
    socket.on('connection', function (data) {
        console.log('Server running on *:' + app.get('port'));
    });
    //socket.emit("connected", {msg: ""});        
    socket.on("chat", function (data) {
        pushToRedis(data.msg);
        //subscriber.ltrim('messages', 0, 99);
        socket.emit("publishMessage", {msg: data.msg});
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    });
});
```

script.js (client):

```
$(function () {
    var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8080/");
    /*
     * -------------------
     * Methods
     * -------------------
     */
    $.fn.clearAndFocus = function () {
        $("#txtMessage").val("").focus();
    };
    $.fn.sendMessageToServer = function () {
        socket.emit("chat", {msg: $("#txtMessage").val()});
        $.fn.clearAndFocus();
    };
    $.fn.clearAndFocus();
    /*
     * -------------------
     * Events
     * -------------------
     */
    $("#btnSend").on("click", function () {
        $.fn.sendMessageToServer();
    });
    $("#txtMessage").on("keyup", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            $.fn.sendMessageToServer();
            $.fn.clearAndFocus();
        }
    });
    /*
     * -------------------
     * Socket Events
     * -------------------
     */
    socket.on('connect', function () {
        console.log("w client is connected");
    });
    socket.on("publishMessage", function (data) {
        console.log(data.msg);
        $(".chatlog").append("\n\
                        <div class=\"chat-row\">\n\
                        <div class=\"chat-text\">" + data.msg + "\n\
                        </div>");

    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    });
});
```

console.log:

```
root@wk11:/var/www/html/wchat/nodejs# nodejs server.js
Option log level is not valid. Please refer to the README.
Server up and running...
redis connection message:{"msg":"56151810ceff6 is connecting..."}
app port :: 8080
chat emtis
Missing error handler on `socket`.
Error: Connection in subscriber mode, only subscriber commands may be used
    at RedisClient.send_command (/var/www/html/wchat/nodejs/node_modules/redis/index.js:751:15)
    at RedisClient.(anonymous function) (/var/www/html/wchat/nodejs/node_modules/redis/index.js:891:21)
    at pushToRedis (/var/www/html/wchat/nodejs/server.js:71:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/wchat/nodejs/server.js:99:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.onevent (/var/www/html/wchat/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:330:8)
    at Socket.onpacket (/var/www/html/wchat/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:290:12)
    at Client.ondecoded (/var/www/html/wchat/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:193:14)
    at Decoder.Emitter.emit (/var/www/html/wchat/nodejs/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:134:20)
    at Decoder.add (/var/www/html/wchat/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io-parser/index.js:247:12)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have create new child object of subscriber in socket.io and it will solve my issue like below described. Because parent object of subscriber is inaccessible in io.sockets.on() and also I had create another child for subscriber.

```
/*
 *  Sender
 */
var publisher = redis.createClient();
/*
 * Receiver
 */
var subscriber = redis.createClient();

/* 
 * -------------------
 * Socket
 * -------------------
 */
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var _subscriber = redis.createClient();
    //console.log("app port :: " + app.get("port"));    
    console.log("Session: %j", sessionHandler);
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(sessionHandler, null, 4));
    socket.on('connection', function (data) {
        console.log('Server running on *:' + app.get('port'));
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

According to Redis documentation:

> Once the client enters the subscribed state it is not supposed to issue any other commands, except for additional SUBSCRIBE, PSUBSCRIBE, UNSUBSCRIBE and PUNSUBSCRIBE commands.

Link: http://redis.io/commands/subscribe

In order to send lpush command you need to create another redis client which is not in subscribed state

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same type of requirement. At the initial render need to show the previously published data after that need to update the newly published data.

While doing this I got the same problem as you.

I resolved this by referring to the answer of @Seyit Caglar Abbasoglu.

Reason for this error.

When Redis is in subscription mode nothing other than publishing, unsubscribing, etc. can be done.

So we need to create two clients, one for fetching the data normally using get and set commands from key/value pair and another one for subscription.

My code goes as below:

```
    import { Request, Response } from 'express';
    import Redis from 'ioredis';
    import 'dotenv/config';
    
    const redis = new Redis({
      host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
      port: Number(process.env.REDIS_PORT),
    });

 const redisForSub = new Redis({
      host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
      port: Number(process.env.REDIS_PORT),
    });
    
    export const getData = async (_: Request, res: Response) => {
      const data = JSON.parse(
        await redis
          .get(REDIS_KEY)
          .then((resp) => resp)
          .catch((err) => err)
      );
    
      if (data.Success) {
        return res.status(200).json({
          success: true,
          data: data,
          message: 'Success',
        });
      }
    
      if (!data.Success) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          success: false,
          message: 'Something went wrong',
        });
      }
    };
    
    export const anotherData = async (_: Request, res: Response) => {
      const dataNeeded = await redis
        .get(REDIS_KEY)
        .then((resp) => resp)
        .catch((err) => err);
    
      const parsedOutput = JSON.parse(dataNeeded);
    
      if (parsedOutput.Success) {
        return res.status(200).json({
          success: true,
          data: parsedOutput,
          message: 'Success',
        });
      }
    
      if (!parsedOutput.Success) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          success: false,
          message: 'Something went wrong',
        });
      }
    };
    
   
    
    export const subscribe = async (_: Request, res: Response) => {
      res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
      });
      res.flushHeaders();
    
      redisForSub.subscribe(CHANNEL_NAME);
    
      redisForSub.on('message', (_, message) => {
        res.write(
          `data: ${JSON.stringify({
            success: true,
            message: 'Success',
            data: JSON.parse(message),
          })}\n\n`
        );
      });
    
      res.on('close', () => {
        console.log('client dropped me');
        res.end();
      });
    };
```